# How to change a UUImage object's grid position based on a UUImageView object that changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am receiving an error trying to move the position of a object with grid properties that represents the location of a picture on a grid screen.

For example, there is a coins object and a player object. These objects are represented on a screen and have properties to represent there current position.

Whenever a player's grid point properties passes a specific area on the screen or passes near the coins grid points property I need to change the coin object grid properties.

**Coins is a UIImage object and Player is a UIImageView object**

I am trying to move the coins picture frame object to a specficed position on the screen but I am recieving the folling error: 
 **Property "center" not found on object of type UIImage ***.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(coins.frame, player.frame)) {
    coins.center = CGPointMake(coins.center.x +50, coins.center.y +165);
}
```

Im working with XCODE, Any suggestion are welcome, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> coins is a UIImage object

is your problem. It has no `center` property. It describes a bunch of pixels not its onscreen representation.

You need to contain each of your coins in a `UIImageView` like your player.